# How to upload a parameter with all tags included?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

For example. I am creating an AMI-ID parameter with Terraform and I want to upload it's value to AWS Parameter store. But also this AMI has a bunch of tags, out of this tags I want a specific value of one of this tag to be uploaded as a parameter as well. How we can create a parameter for a tag?

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "ami_id" {
 name  = ami_id
 type  = "String"
 value = data.aws_ami.centos_ami.id
 provide = aws.us-west-2
 overwrite = true
}
```

Comment: Your question title says you want to include all the tags. Your question content says you want to find a specific tag value, and create a new parameter from that.

Answer (score 2):

Your question title and question content are not the same.

---

If you want to find a specific tag on the AMI, and create a new SSM Parameter from that, then it would look like this:

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "ami_tag_value" {
 name  = "ami_tag_value"
 type  = "String"
 value = data.aws_ami.centos_ami.tags[index(data.aws_ami.centos_ami.tags.*.key, "tag_name")].value
 provide = aws.us-west-2
 overwrite = true
}
```

Where `"tag_name"` is the name of the tag you want the value for.

---

If you want to copy all the tags from the AMI to the SSM parameter, it would look like this:

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "ami_id" {
 name  = ami_id
 type  = "String"
 value = data.aws_ami.centos_ami.id
 provide = aws.us-west-2
 overwrite = true
 tags = data.aws_ami.centos_ami.tags
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This what exactly I was looking for.